# LocationManager and LocationClient together to get user location

Tags: android, location

I simply need to get the user location. Preferably the exactly location, but if it's not possible, a rough location would be fine.

According to the docs:

[LocationClient.getLastLocation()](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationClient.html#getLastLocation%28%29)

`Returns the best most recent location currently available.`

and

[LocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#getLastKnownLocation%28java.lang.String%29)

`Returns a Location indicating the data from the last known location fix obtained from the given provider.`

If my understanding is right, the former will give me a very good result (or null sometimes) while the latter will give me a result which would rarely be null.

This is my code (simplified)

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);

@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle dataBundle) {
    setUserLocation();
}

private void setUserLocation() {
    myLocation = locationClient.getLastLocation();

    if (myLocation == null) {
        myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(new Criteria(), false));
        if (myLocation == null) {
            //I give up, just set the map somewhere and warn the user.
            myLocation = new Location("");
            myLocation.setLatitude(-22.624152);
            myLocation.setLongitude(-44.385624);
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.location_not_found, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } else {
        isMyLocationOK = true;
    }
}
```

It seems to be working but my questions are:

1. Is my understanding of `getLastLocation` and `getLastKnownLocation` correct?
2. Is this a good approach?
3. Can I get in trouble using both in the same activity?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`LocationClient.getLastLocation()` only returns `null` if a location fix is impossible to determine. `getLastLocation()` is no *worse* than `getLastKnownLocation()`, and is usually much better. I don't think it's worth "falling back" to `getLastKnownLocation()` as you do.

You can't get into trouble using both, but it's overkill.

Of course, you have to remember that `LocationClient` is part of *Google Play Services*, so it's only available on devices whose platform includes Google Play Store. Some devices may be using a non-standard version of Android, and you won't have access to `LocationClient`.

The documentation for Google Play Services discusses this in more detail.

Comment: Good to know! I already have code to handle the availability of Google Play (in fact may app just don't work without it). At first I used only LocationServices but many times I got weird results from it. Switching to LocationClient gave me much better results, but also null results in many cases which I could not reproduce. I thought that the Android system may record the last known location in some place which would be only accessible to the LocationService class, hence my code above. If that's not true, then it's better to rely only on LocationClient, right?

Comment: See this [flow](http://developer.android.com/images/location/getting-location.png) of the [official developer web.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html)